# attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase in multiple sqlite handler file

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm changing my file organization for mysqlite files.
Before, I had all methods for all tables in 1 file : DatabaseHandler

The file looks like that :

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mybase.db";
private static final String TABLE_TIENDA = "tienda";
private static final String TABLE_PROYECTO = "proyecto";
// Columns Name

private static final String TIENDA_ID = "id";
private static final String TIENDA_CANAL = "canal";
private static final String TIENDA_CIUDAD = "ciudad";
    ...

private static String CREATE_PDV_PROYECTO = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PROYECTO + "(" + PROYECTO_ID
        + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + PROYECTO_PLAN_ID + " INTEGER," + PROYECTO_DESC + " TEXT," + PROYECTO_VIGENCIA
        + " TEXT," + PROYECTO_ACTIVO + " INTEGER)";

    ...

SQLiteDatabase db = null;

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {

    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    db = this.getReadableDatabase();
}

public void addProyecto(Proyecto p) {
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(PROYECTO_ID, p.proyectoid);
    values.put(PROYECTO_PLAN_ID, p.planid);
    values.put(PROYECTO_DESC, p.proyectodsc);
    values.put(PROYECTO_VIGENCIA, p.vigencia);
    values.put(PROYECTO_ACTIVO, p.activo);

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_PROYECTO, null, values);
    Log.e("DB", "inserting project:" + p.proyectodsc);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}
```

The thing is I work in several tables : Tienda, Proyecto, Captura and more.
The Java Object Tinda has a Proyecto Object inside.

The thing is I wanted to separate each Table in a separated file.
So I create clases DatabaseHandler, TiendaHandler, ProyectoHandler and CapturaHandler.

The thing in TiendaHandler is I use ProyectoHandler references which produce the error in the title :

```
public void addAllTienda(ArrayList<Pdv> ltiendas) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    for (Pdv tienda : ltiendas) {
        addTienda(tienda);
        Proyecto p = tienda.getProyecto();
        int proyectoId = p.proyectoid;
        if (!ProyectoHandler.existProyecto(db, proyectoId)) { // THis line produce error
            ProyectoHandler.addProyecto(db, p);
        }
    }
    db.close();
}
```

I don't know how to do it? It is good practice what I'm doing???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `db.close()` then you can't use this object again.

You should get a new reference to the DB using again `getWritableDatabase()`.

A good thing to do: Don't save a reference to the Database, everytime you need to use it use open it and when you are done close it. Don't keep a reference alive more than it needs.

I refer to this

```
SQLiteDatabase db = null;
```

in `DatabaseHandler`

In your `addProyecto` you create a new reference to `getWritableDatabase` so the reference created in `DatabaseHandler` is losed. Since you close the reference inside `addProyecto` (with `db.close`) when you use the object `db` in other methods of `DatabaseHandler` you will get this `Exception`.

A way to fix it is to remove this

```
SQLiteDatabase db = null;
```

from the class and open/close the database in every method.

Comment: I don't understand everything you say. Can you please explain the last phrase??? In my code, each iteration of addTienda open and close a db object. But it should not affect the other db object defined in addAllTienda. That's why I'm lost!